# Perlin noise artifacts

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, perlin-noise

I've taken the [Wikipedia Perlin Noise Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Pseudocode) and implemented it in Python, here is the code:

```
import random
import math
from PIL import Image
from decimal import Decimal


IMAGE_SIZE = 200
PERLIN_RESOLUTION = 10
GRADIENT = []


for x in range(PERLIN_RESOLUTION + 1):
    GRADIENT.append([])
    for y in range(PERLIN_RESOLUTION + 1):
        angle = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
        vector = (
            Decimal(math.cos(angle)),
            Decimal(math.sin(angle))
        )
        GRADIENT[x].append(vector)


def lerp(a0, a1, w):
    return (1 - w)*a0 + w*a1


def dotGridGradient(ix, iy, x, y):

    dx = x - Decimal(ix)
    dy = y - Decimal(iy)

    return (dx*GRADIENT[iy][ix][0] + dy*GRADIENT[iy][ix][1])


def perlin(x, y):
    if x > 0.0:
        x0 = int(x)
    else:
        x0 = int(x) - 1
    x1 = x0 + 1
    if y > 0.0:
        y0 = int(y)
    else:
        y0 = int(y) - 1
    y1 = y0 + 1

    sx = x - Decimal(x0)
    sy = y - Decimal(y0)

    n0 = dotGridGradient(x0, y0, x, y)
    n1 = dotGridGradient(x1, y0, x, y)
    ix0 = lerp(n0, n1, sx)
    n0 = dotGridGradient(x0, y1, x, y)
    n1 = dotGridGradient(x1, y1, x, y)
    ix1 = lerp(n0, n1, sx)
    value = lerp(ix0, ix1, sy)

    return value


image = Image.new('RGB', (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
pixels = image.load()
for i in range(IMAGE_SIZE):
    x = Decimal(i) / IMAGE_SIZE
    for j in range(IMAGE_SIZE):
        y = Decimal(j) / IMAGE_SIZE
        value = perlin(x * 10, y * 10)
        greyscale = (value + 1) * 255 / 2
        pixels[i, j] = (greyscale, greyscale, greyscale)
image.save('artifacts.png', 'PNG')
```

Here is the resulting image that is created by the script:

[image: Perlin with artifacts]

I must be missing something here, you can very clearly see the vertices.  Can anyone let me know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [smoothstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) instead of linear interpolation.

```
def smoothstep(a0, a1, w):
    value = w*w*w*(w*(w*6 - 15) + 10)
    return a0 + value*(a1 - a0)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your response, WhatEvDev.  I tried it out and it seemed to work great.  I want to accept your answer, but before I do could you explain why this function is better (and why so many example algorithms  online seem to use lerp, like Wikipedia).

Comment: Linear interpolation is used as an example because it's the simplest interpolation (`value = w`). If you use 1D Perlin Noise with lerp,  you will get polygonal curve.
In order to get smooth result, you need to interpolate smoothly between points. For that you need a function that has zero first derivative (and possibly also second derivative) at 0 and 1. If you use 1D Perlin Noise with smoothstep, you will get smooth curve.